# How do I include JWT with multer?

Tags: jwt, multer

I have been using JWT for most of my api like this:

```
app.post("/api/customer", jwt , (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.body.customers)        
    })
```

and now I have an api with multer and I'm not sure how or where I should include the jwt:

```
app.post("/upload/single", uploadStorage.single("csv"), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file)
  return res.send("Single file")
})
```

How should go about it? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. Thanks again.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025277/jwt-token-and-multer-for-file-uploads-node) what you looking for?

Comment: Thanks MrMoeinM. I will give a try. Thanks again.