# Having trouble with Multer and JWT

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, multer

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around this:

Basically I am trying to verify the users token before uploading the file with multer.
The problem is the JWT from the cookie is "undefined".

This is the route snippet:

```
router.post("/files/user/:userId", verifyJWT, upload.single("file"), controllerFunction);
```

In my verifyJWT method I'm doing:

```
exports.verifyJWT = async (req, res, next) => {
  let accesToken = req.cookies.jwt;

  if (!accesToken) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      message: "Acces is unauthorized.",
    });
  }

  let payload;

  try {
    payload = jwt.verify(accesToken, process.env.JWT_KEY);
    req.name = payload.name;
    req.type = payload.type;
    req._id = payload._id;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(403).json({ message: "Token could not be verified!" });
  }
};
```

If my route has the **verifyJWT middleware** for whatever reason when I'm calling **console.log(accesToken)** the acces token is sent as undefined.

If i remove the middleware verifyJWT from the "/files/user/:userId" route, and **console.log(accesToken)** I'm receiving the token.

This only happens on the route which has the multer upload callback in it.

I have already tried the suggestions from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025277/jwt-token-and-multer-for-file-uploads-node)  but for whatever reason it does not seem to work

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Do you use the `cookie-parser` middleware referred to by the [`req.cookies` documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.cookies)?

Comment: Thanks :)

Yes, I use cookie-parser in my server.js file. The thing is the problem with the undefined JWT from the middleware only happens on the route with the "upload.single("file")" from the multer. Basically all my other routes which use the verifyJWT work perfectly fine. (with the accesToken being there)

Comment: Do you do `console.log(accesToken)` in your `controllerFunction`? Because it's not in the code you shared.

Comment: No, I'm logging it inside the verifyJWT function, I just did not add it in the snippet code.

Comment: But if you remove the `verifyJWT` function, how to you then know that you receive the token? Can you share more of your code, perhaps?

Comment: Because the token is used in other areas of the application.  In my front-end I'm using React. Basically I have other parts of my code where I'm checking for the token so I can render different components based on the payload from the token. So in other routes that I am using the verifyJWT method, if I'm logging the console.log(accesToken) I am getting the token back.

Comment: Furthermore, I can see the token in the Application Tab from my Browser. So I guess the token is definitely there, but somehow if I'm applying multer all of a sudden it goes undefined. I'm not sure what to share - if there's something you think could help I'll definitely post it. My controller has a basic insert functionality into my MongoDB Cluster.

Comment: Hi did you get a solution. Please i need the help